# Entity Framework Core 6 no many to many collections generated on Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am very confused to why I am running into the opposite issue that many people seem to have so I really hope I am making a mistake.

I am using the latest version of Entity Framework Core 6 (6.0.10)

I am executing the following command.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir "Models2"
```

[image]

I have a very simple database setup with a many to many relationship.

[image]

I tried SQL Server and Postgresql so it is not a problem in versioning of the Entity Framework Core.

What I want:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

[This guy](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28296) for example is having the "problem" I want but I see no difference between him and me. Already thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `--table` parameter and passing only `Foo` and `Bar` explicitly? Also, are you sure your tables have the proper primary-key/foreign-key relationships setup? Your model picture shows a different graphic on the Foo.Id column compared to the Bar.Id column.

Comment: @julealgon Yes I have tried --table and it resulted in no list at all and i updateded my image to the actual one it shouldve been

Comment: After long digging I noticed my missunderstanding of join tables. An explicit Primary key wont generate my wanted output. A composite primary does.